# Formula to search a set of cells in columns for 3 letters (each cell contains one letter)

Tags: excel-formula

Looking for a formula to search a set of cells in columns for 3 letters (each cell contains one letter)  and output 2 in case 2/3 letters match and output 3 incase 3/3 matches.

I am trying to search a column  A1:A4, B1:B4, C1:C4, D1:D4 etc where its contents are F,N,S,O

A1: F
A2: N
A3: S
A4: O

So while searching for A1:A4, I need the desired output: 3

Sample excel sheet

```
    F       F       F
    N       N       S
    O       S       O
    O       O       O

    2       3       2
```

First column has F & N, so output = 2
Second column has F, S & N only, so output = 3

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what are you searching for.

Comment: I have added an example, Let me know if it gives clarity to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest approach:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A4,"F")>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(A1:A4,"S")>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(A1:A4,"N")>0,1,0)
```

Comment: You are welcome :) Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it suits you needs. Thanks